# Nested Looping in Laravel Blade Templating

Tags: laravel

**Here is my Controller**

When I run this controller code I get the result as in the screenshot below, as all data is correct.

```
$query = DB::table('intis_auctions_lots')
        ->select('bidincrement','intis_lot_id','lot','product_name','maxbid','enddate')
        ->where([['community_name','=',$CommunityNo],['SellerId','=',$SellerId],['active','=','Y'],['startdate','<',$now],['enddate','>',$now]])
        ->orderBy('intis_lot_id')
        ->get();

foreach($query as $querys) {
    $qintis_lot_id = $querys->intis_lot_id;
    $qenddate = date('H:i', strtotime($querys->enddate));

    $individualbids = DB::table('intis_auctions_lots')
            ->select(DB::raw('sum(nrbids) as nbid,lot, startprice,intis_lot_id,product_name,enddate,maxbid'))    
            ->where([['community_name','=',$CommunityNo],['SellerId','=',$SellerId],['active','=','Y'],['startdate','<',$now],['enddate','>',$now],['intis_lot_id','=',$qintis_lot_id]])
            ->groupBy('startprice','intis_lot_id','product_name','lot','enddate','maxbid')
            ->get();   

    foreach($individualbids as $key => $value)
        echo  "<tr><td>".$value->lot."</td>
        <td>".$value->intis_lot_id."</td>
        <td>".$value->product_name."</td>
        <td>".date('H:i', strtotime($value->enddate))."</td>
        <td>".$value->startprice."</td>
        <td>".$value->maxbid."</td>
        </tr>";
    }
}
```

[image: Check this image]

My View code as below

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="zero_config" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Lot</th>
                <th>Product Name</th> 
                <th>End Time</th>   
                <th>Bids</th>    
                <th>Start Price</th>    
                <th>Current Bid Amount</th> 
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>               
            @foreach ($query as $key=>$value) 
                @foreach ($individualbids as $key => $value1)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $value->lot }}</td>
                        <td style="text-align:left">{{ $value->intis_lot_id }},{{ $value->product_name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ date('H:i', strtotime($value->enddate)) }}</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>{{ $value1->startprice }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $value->maxbid }}</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach 
            @endforeach 
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

When pass it to the view I'm getting result as in the screen below, as the Starting Price as 340 it takes the first value to all the row as same value, but when I run in the controller code without passing to view it show correct value. Please provide me the solution to write the proper code in the view, as it will helpful to me.

[image: Check image]

Comment: `$value1->startprice`

Comment: Hi Bhavinjr, I'm not getting what you mean to say, but it is  already $value1->startprice as to display the  Price value